# How to improve a backtraching sudoku solving algorithm in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, runtime, sudoku

I wrote a backtracking Sudoku solving algorithm in Python.
It solves a 2D array like this (zero means "empty field"):

```
[
  [7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 3],
  [0, 9, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0],
  [6, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 3, 0, 9, 0],
  [5, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
]
```

like this:

```
[
  [7, 5, 8, 2, 4, 9, 1, 6, 3], 
  [4, 9, 3, 1, 5, 6, 8, 2, 7], 
  [2, 1, 6, 8, 3, 7, 4, 5, 9],
  [9, 3, 5, 4, 7, 1, 2, 8, 6],
  [6, 4, 2, 3, 8, 5, 9, 7, 1], 
  [8, 7, 1, 9, 6, 2, 5, 3, 4], 
  [3, 2, 7, 5, 9, 4, 6, 1, 8], 
  [1, 8, 4, 6, 2, 3, 7, 9, 5], 
  [5, 6, 9, 7, 1, 8, 3, 4, 2]
]
```

But for "hard" Sudokus (where there are a lot of zeros at the beginning), it's quite slow. It takes the algorithm around 9 seconds to solve the Sudoku above. That's a lot better then what I startet with (90 seconds), but still slow.

I think that the "deepcopy" can somehow be improved/replaced (because it is executed 103.073 times in the example below), but my basic approaches were slower..

I heard of 0.01 second C/C++ solutions but I'm not sure if those are backtracking algorithms of some kind of mathematical solution...

This is my whole algorithm with 2 example Sudokus:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def is_sol_row(mat,row,val):
  m = len(mat)
  for i in range(m):
    if mat[row][i] == val:
      return False
  return True

def is_sol_col(mat,col,val):
  m = len(mat)
  for i in range(m):
    if mat[i][col] == val:
      return False
  return True

def is_sol_block(mat,row,col,val):
  rainbow = [0,0,0,3,3,3,6,6,6]
  i = rainbow[row]
  j = rainbow[col]
  elements = {
    mat[i + 0][j + 0], mat[i + 1][j + 0], mat[i + 2][j + 0],
    mat[i + 0][j + 1], mat[i + 1][j + 1], mat[i + 2][j + 1],
    mat[i + 0][j + 2], mat[i + 1][j + 2], mat[i + 2][j + 2],
  }
  if val in elements:
    return False
  return True

def is_sol(mat,row,col,val):
  return is_sol_row(mat,row,val) and is_sol_col(mat,col,val) and is_sol_block(mat,row,col,val)

def findAllZeroIndizes(mat):
  m = len(mat)
  indizes = []
  for i in range(m):
    for j in range(m):
      if mat[i][j] == 0:
        indizes.append((i,j))
  return indizes

def sudoku(mat):
  q = [(mat,0)]
  zeroIndizes = findAllZeroIndizes(mat)
  while q:
    t,numSolvedIndizes = q.pop()
    if numSolvedIndizes == len(zeroIndizes):
      return t
    else:
      i,j = zeroIndizes[numSolvedIndizes]
      for k in range(1,10):
        if is_sol(t,i,j,k):
          newt = deepcopy(t)
          newt[i][j] = k
          q.append((newt,numSolvedIndizes+1))
  return False


mat = [
  [7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 3],
  [0, 9, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0],
  [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0],

  [0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0],
  [6, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0],

  [0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  [0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 3, 0, 9, 0],
  [5, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2],
]

# mat = [
#   [3, 0, 6, 5, 0, 8, 4, 0, 0],
#   [5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#   [0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1],
#   [0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8, 0],
#   [9, 0, 0, 8, 6, 3, 0, 0, 5],
#   [0, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0, 6, 0, 0],
#   [1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0],
#   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4],
#   [0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0]
# ]

print(sudoku(mat))
```

Comment: If your code is complete and work and you are looking for improvement suggestions, it should be on Code Review instead. This site is primarily for fixing broken code.

Comment: A 0.01 second solution is possible with backtracking. Instead of using a fixed scan order (by rows and columns), use a best-first scan order (by the square that has fewest allowed values). In your example, the only allowed value at {4,5} is 5. So that's the square the algorithm should choose first. That leaves only 2 choices (4 or 6) for {1,5}, so {1,5} is the next square to be solved. Using a best-first scan order, it only takes 612 attempts (and .002 seconds) to solve the puzzle.

Comment: @user3386109 Thanks for your answer. Can you explain what you mean by "value at {4,5}"? What does {4,5} mean? row 4, col 5? I don't understand why there is only the 5 possible.

Comment: Yes, {4,5} means row 4, col 5, where rows and cols are numbered starting with 0. The block has numbers 4,8,2. The row additionally has 1,6 and the column additionally has 3,7,9. So the only possible number at {4,5} is 5.

Comment: see also [speed up backtracking sudoku solver](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/226455)

Comment: One example is not enough to prove that optimized backtracking can be fast. You have to start with a worst-case sudoku with respect to backtracking, not a worst-case for human solvers. Then you have to calculate the expected number of steps to solve. With no optimizations, that is a number about 77 digits long, 9 to the 81 power. The actual expected steps may be practical or impractical; I'm not smart enough to do the calculation.

Answer (score 3):

The largest time sink is that, for *every* open position, you try *each* of the nine digits, without learning anything about the attempts.  Your test grid has 56 open grid locations, so anything you do is magnified through that lens.  A little preprocessing will go a long way.  For instance, make a list of available numbers in each row and column.  Key that appropriately, and use that for your search instead of range(m).

Another technique is to apply simple algorithms to make trivial placements as they become available.  For instance, you can quickly derive the `1` in the upper-left block, and the missing `7`s in the left and middle columns of blocks.  This alone cuts the solution time in half.  Wherever you're down to a single choice for what number goes in a selected open square, or where a selected number can be placed in a particular row/col/block, then make that placement before you engage in exhaustive backtracking.